# How do I properly use nested classes in my hpp file and cpp file?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am trying to implement a singly linked list with an iterator as a nested class of the linked list class. I am getting a lot of errors that I think have to do with working with my iterators. I have spent a few hours researching this, but unfortunately a lot of the solutions include templates and I'm not able to use those. Every time I fix one problem, a new one shows up.

I'm getting the below errors in my cpp file:

- Use of undeclared identifier 'current'
- Expected ';' after top level declarator (I'm very confused on why I'm getting this because I thought I delared iterator in my hpp file
- Overloaded 'operator++' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type (we're not supposed to have parameters for our overloaded operators in this case, right? I just want to iterate so that I am now pointing to the next item in a linked list
- Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
- 'Iterator' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

I will continue to do more research and report back here if I figure out what is wrong with my code to hopefully help if others have the same question.

Thanks so much in advance!

Here is my hpp file:

```
#ifndef linkedlist_h
#define linkedlist_h


  class LinkedList {
  public:


    struct Node {
      //Node(Node *aNext=nullptr) : next(aNext) {}
        int  value;   //this is the value you want to save
        Node *next;  //this points to the next node in the list (or nullptr)
    };
    //friend class Iterator; //do Ineed this even though it's a nested class

    Node *root;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    //add a NESTED Interator class...
    class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator(); //default constructor
        Iterator(Node* aNode);//constructor
        ~Iterator(); //dtor
        Iterator operator++();
        Iterator operator++(int);
        bool operator==(const Iterator &anIterator);
        bool operator!=(const Iterator &anIterator);
        int operator*();
        operator Node*();
        Node *current; //do I need to put LinkedList since it's a nested class?

      //add all the necessary operators

    protected:
    };

    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    LinkedList(); //default constructor...
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& aCopy); //copy ctor
    ~LinkedList(); //dtor
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& aCopy); //assignment operator

    void append(int value);
    void prepend(int value);
    void remove(int value);
    int size(); //needs to return unsigned int????
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
    Iterator find(int value);


  protected:
  };




#endif /* linkedlist_h */
```

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"


//class Iterator;
  LinkedList::LinkedList() {
      root=nullptr;
  }

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& aCopy){ //copy ctor
    Node *temp=aCopy.root;
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    root=newNode;

    while (temp != nullptr){
        newNode-> value=temp->value;
        temp=temp->next;
        if (temp !=nullptr){
            newNode->next=new Node;
            newNode=newNode->next;
        }
        else{ newNode->next=nullptr;}
    }
}

LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList &aCopy){ //assignment operator
    while(root!=nullptr){
        Node* oneBefore= root;
        root =root->next;
        delete oneBefore;
    }
    Node *newNode= new Node;
    Node *temp=aCopy.root;
    root=newNode;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        newNode->value=temp->value;
        temp=temp->next;
        if(temp!=nullptr){
            newNode->next=new Node;
            newNode=newNode->next;
        }
        else{newNode->next=nullptr;}
    }
    return *this;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){ //dtor
    Node* oneBefore = nullptr;
    while(root!=nullptr){
        oneBefore=root;
        root=root->next;
        delete oneBefore;
    }
}

void LinkedList::append(int value){
    Node* newNode=new Node;
    newNode->value=value;
    if(root!=nullptr){
        Node* temp = root;
        while (temp->next !=nullptr){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next=nullptr;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    if(root==nullptr){
        newNode->next=nullptr;
        root=newNode;
    }

}

void LinkedList::prepend(int value){
    Node* newNode=new Node;
    newNode->value=value;
    if (root!=nullptr){
        newNode->next=root;
        root=newNode;
    }
    if(root==nullptr){
        root=newNode;
        newNode->next=nullptr;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(int value){
    if(root==nullptr){
        Node *before=nullptr;
        Node *temp=root;
        if(temp->value==value){
            root=temp->next;
        }
        else{
            while(temp->value!=value &&temp->next != nullptr){
                before=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            if(temp->value==value){
                before->next=temp->next;
            }
        }
        delete temp;
    }
}

int LinkedList::size(){
    Node* aNode = root;
    int numElements=0;
    while(aNode!=nullptr){
        aNode=aNode->next;
        numElements=numElements+1;
    }
    return numElements;
}

LinkedList::Iterator LinkedList::begin(){
    return LinkedList::Iterator(root);
}

LinkedList::Iterator LinkedList::end(){
    Node *aNode=root;
    while(aNode!=nullptr){
        aNode=aNode->next;
    }
    return LinkedList::Iterator(aNode);
}

LinkedList::Iterator Iterator(){
    current=nullptr;
}
LinkedList::Iterator(Node *aNode){
    current=aNode;
}

LinkedList::Iterator operator++(){//I have no idea what the difference is supposed to be between this one and the one below
    current=current->next;
    return *this;
}

LinkedList::Iterator& Iterator::operator=(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy){ //assignment operator
    current=aCopy.current;
    return *this;
}

bool Iterator::operator !=(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy){
    return current != aCopy.current;
}

bool Iterator::operator==(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy){
    return current==aCopy.current;
}

int Iterator::operator*(){
    return current->value;
}
```

UPDATE: The suggestions below helped so much! Thank you so much! The last error I have is (I'll mark where it is shown on the compiler below):
 - "Definition of implicitly declared copy assignment operator"

Updated hpp file:

```
#ifndef linkedlist_h
#define linkedlist_h


  class LinkedList {
  public:


    struct Node {
      //Node(Node *aNext=nullptr) : next(aNext) {}
        int  value;   //this is the value you want to save
        Node *next;  //this points to the next node in the list (or nullptr)
    };
    //friend class Iterator; //do Ineed this even though it's a nested class

    Node *root;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    //add a NESTED Interator class...
    class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator();//default constructor
        //Iterator() : current(nullptr) {}
        Iterator(Node* aNode);
        //Iterator(Node* aNode): current(aNode){};//constructor
        ~Iterator(); //dtor
        Iterator operator++();
        Iterator operator++(int);
        bool operator==(const Iterator &anIterator);
        bool operator!=(const Iterator &anIterator);
        int operator*();
        operator Node*();
        Node *current; //do I need to put LinkedList since it's a nested class?

      //add all the necessary operators

    protected:
    };

    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    LinkedList(); //default constructor...
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& aCopy); //copy ctor
    ~LinkedList(); //dtor
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& aCopy); //assignment operator

    void append(int value);
    void prepend(int value);
    void remove(int value);
    int size(); //needs to return unsigned int????
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
    Iterator find(int value);


  protected:
  };




#endif /* linkedlist_h */
```

Updated cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"


//class Iterator;
  LinkedList::LinkedList() {
      root=nullptr;
  }

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& aCopy){ //copy ctor
    Node *temp=aCopy.root;
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    root=newNode;

    while (temp != nullptr){
        newNode-> value=temp->value;
        temp=temp->next;
        if (temp !=nullptr){
            newNode->next=new Node;
            newNode=newNode->next;
        }
        else{ newNode->next=nullptr;}
    }
}

LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList &aCopy){ //assignment operator
    while(root!=nullptr){
        Node* oneBefore= root;
        root =root->next;
        delete oneBefore;
    }
    Node *newNode= new Node;
    Node *temp=aCopy.root;
    root=newNode;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        newNode->value=temp->value;
        temp=temp->next;
        if(temp!=nullptr){
            newNode->next=new Node;
            newNode=newNode->next;
        }
        else{newNode->next=nullptr;}
    }
    return *this;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){ //dtor
    Node* oneBefore = nullptr;
    while(root!=nullptr){
        oneBefore=root;
        root=root->next;
        delete oneBefore;
    }
}

void LinkedList::append(int value){
    Node* newNode=new Node;
    newNode->value=value;
    if(root!=nullptr){
        Node* temp = root;
        while (temp->next !=nullptr){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newNode->next=nullptr;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    if(root==nullptr){
        newNode->next=nullptr;
        root=newNode;
    }

}

void LinkedList::prepend(int value){
    Node* newNode=new Node;
    newNode->value=value;
    if (root!=nullptr){
        newNode->next=root;
        root=newNode;
    }
    if(root==nullptr){
        root=newNode;
        newNode->next=nullptr;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(int value){
    if(root==nullptr){
        Node *before=nullptr;
        Node *temp=root;
        if(temp->value==value){
            root=temp->next;
        }
        else{
            while(temp->value!=value &&temp->next != nullptr){
                before=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            if(temp->value==value){
                before->next=temp->next;
            }
        }
        delete temp;
    }
}

int LinkedList::size(){
    Node* aNode = root;
    int numElements=0;
    while(aNode!=nullptr){
        aNode=aNode->next;
        numElements=numElements+1;
    }
    return numElements;
}

LinkedList::Iterator LinkedList::begin(){
    return LinkedList::Iterator(root);
}

LinkedList::Iterator LinkedList::end(){
    Node *aNode=root;
    while(aNode!=nullptr){
        aNode=aNode->next;
    }
    return LinkedList::Iterator(aNode);
}

LinkedList::Iterator::Iterator() : current(nullptr) {}

LinkedList::Iterator::Iterator(Node* aNode): current(aNode){};

LinkedList::Iterator LinkedList::Iterator::operator++(){//I have no idea what the difference is supposed to be between this one and the one below
    current=current->next;
    return *this;
}

LinkedList::Iterator& LinkedList::Iterator::operator=(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy) noexcept{ //assignment operator; THIS IS WHERE I SEE AN ERROR
    current=aCopy.current;
    return *this;
}

bool LinkedList::Iterator::operator !=(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy){
    return current != aCopy.current;
}

bool LinkedList::Iterator::operator==(const LinkedList::Iterator& aCopy){
    return current==aCopy.current;
}

int LinkedList::Iterator::operator*(){
    return current->value;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax for defining member functions of nested classes is all wrong. E,g, `Iterator` constructor should look like this: `LinkedList::Iterator(){ current=nullptr; }` or better still, `LinkedList::Iterator() : current(nullptr) {}`

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I've since made those changes, but have a new error: "Expected unqualified-id" so it's back to the drawing board!

Comment: Well, if you'd like further assistance, edit your question to show the code you have now, and the complete text of all error messages. I for one cannot help with code I cannot see.

Comment: In fact, the constructor should look like this: `LinkedList::Iterator::Iterator() : current(nullptr) {}`, and all other member functions of the nested class should look like `bool LinkedList::Iterator::operator!=() { ... }` and so on

Comment: @Bizzarrus, wow! That cleared up all but one of my issues! Thank you so much! I super appreciate it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll update the code at the end of my post so the "wrong" code is preserved for people who are having the same problems!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem (as I already said as a comment) was, that the definitions of nested class methods should look like `LinkedList::Iterator::Iterator() { ... }` or `bool LinkedList::Iterator::operator!=(...) { ... }`. (I just write this here again to make it easier to find, if someone else has the same problem)

The reason why you get an error in the definition of the assignment operator is simply that you haven't declared an assignment operator for that class in your header.

As a bonus round: The difference between `operator++()` and `operator++(int)` is, that the first one is called with `++a` (pre-increment), while the other one is called with `a++` (post-increment). The pre-increment one should also return a reference to the same object (similar to the assingment operator), while the post-increment returns a copy of of the object as it was before the increment.